# How to get rid of a lock by getting an error instead (or skipping it) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, locking

I am trying to not get locked on a specific query in SQL Server.

### Use case - High Load Parallel Processing

I need a way to handle "work queues" using SQL Server and its transactionnal system to ensure that the work has been completed (with the integrated rollback of SQL Server transaction in case of a unhandled failure like a IIS pool crash/recycle or app crash).

The system has to be able to handle many workers (I call them "WorkerApp") which will that have to do some random work ("Work Item") and do parallel processing, one work item should NOT be run twice in any case (even high load).

I want to have an error (anything even 'SQL Victim') or any way to understand that a row is being used, instead of a real lock which will result in blocks/deadlocks... which I really don't want because it will just result in a poor performance in my use case.

### SQL Structure and value initialisation of this example :

```
CREATE TABLE [worker].[Item](
    [ItemId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Content] [xml] NULL,
    [IsRunning] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Item] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ItemId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [worker].[Item] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Item_IsRunning]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsRunning]
GO

INSERT INTO worker.Item (IsRunning) VALUES (0)
INSERT INTO worker.Item (IsRunning) VALUES (0)
```

### First script simulating a long work

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;


BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @workId BIGINT;

SELECT TOP 1
    @workId = ItemId
FROM
    worker.Item
WHERE 
    IsRunning = 0
;


SELECT @workId;

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
UPDATE 
    worker.Item
SET
    IsRunning = 1
WHERE
    ItemId = @workId
;

WAITFOR DELAY '00:05:00'
PRINT 'Finished'

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

### Second problematic script ran in parallel and locking (which is what I am trying to avoid)

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
set deadlock_priority low
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;


DECLARE @workId BIGINT;

SELECT TOP 1
    @workId = ItemId
FROM
    worker.Item
WHERE 
    IsRunning = 1
;

-- Here is where I don't want it to lock
UPDATE 
    worker.Item
SET
    IsRunning = 0
WHERE
    ItemId = 1
;

SELECT * FROM worker.Item
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

### What I am trying to achieve

The goal would be the second script to run and fail instantly (or have a way to know that the update didnt complete because of a lock) when it tries to update a record that has been hold by the SERIALIZABLE.

Any other solution that would protect each work item (in "IsRunning" state) would be interesting for me. The SERIALIZABLE was just an attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[ 1 ]** First thing: instead of using a two steps approach with a `SELECT TOP(1) ...` and then `UPDATE ...` plus one transaction I would use a single `UPDATE` thus:

```
UPDATE TOP(1)
    worker.Item
SET
    IsRunning = 1,
    @ItemId = ItemId 
WHERE IsRunning = 0;
SELECT @ItemId
```

Notes:

**1.1** `UPDATE TOP(1)` will update maximum one row `WHERE IsRunning = 0`

**1.2** And `@ItemId = ItemId` (yep, it's possible to do this) will copy into `@ItemId` scalar variable the value of `ItemId` column.

**[ 2 ]** If you want to get an error / exception when following source code

```
UPDATE 
    worker.Item
SET
    IsRunning = 0
WHERE
    ItemId = 1
```

is executed and also when current row is locked (by another concurrent connect / Tx) then I would use `SET LOCK_TIMEOUT` thus: {`-1` (default) means wait forever if row has an incompatible lock granted to a concurrent connection, `0` (non default) means it will not wait, instead an error / exception will be raised}:

```
...
SET LOCK_TIMEOUT -1 -- Default behaviour
SELECT TOP 1
    @workId = ItemId
FROM
    worker.Item
WHERE 
    IsRunning = 1
;

-- Here is where I don't want it to lock
SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 0 -- Raise an exception if row is locked
UPDATE 
    worker.Item
SET
    IsRunning = 0
WHERE
    ItemId = 1
...
```

Result: second statement will raise following exception
[image]

**[ 3 ]** Also, if for second script, the goal is to skip locked rows (by other concurrent connection/Tx) then one solution is to use [`READPAST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table)  (and also `ROWLOCK`) table hint(s) together with `READ COMMITTED` or `REPEATABLE READ` isolation levels thus:

**[3.1]**

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
...
SELECT TOP 1
    @workId = ItemId
FROM
    worker.Item WITH(READPAST, ROWLOCK)
WHERE 
    IsRunning = 1
```

or

**[3.2]**

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
...
;WITH cte
AS (
SELECT  TOP(1)
        q.workId, q.IsRunning
FROM    Work.Item AS q WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
WHERE   q.IsRunning = 0
ORDER BY q.workId
)
UPDATE  cte 
SET     @workId = workId,
        IsRunning = 1;
```

**[ 4 ]** Anyway, original requirement is not clear. If none of above answers doesn't fit then you should add more info.

**[ 5 ]** I would use following approach:

Instead of `IsRunning BIT` I would use `IsProccesed BIT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Item_IsProcessed' DEFAULT(0)` and then within transaction I would use single step approach from [ 1 ] thus:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN

    DECLARE @Id INT;
    WITH cte
    AS (
    SELECT  TOP(1)
            q.Id, q.IsProcessed
    FROM    Work.Item AS q WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
    WHERE   q.IsProcessed = 0
    ORDER BY q.Id
    )
    UPDATE  cte 
    SET     @Id = Id,
            IsProcessed = 1;

    ...
    source code to process item @Id
    ...

COMMIT 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK
END
... other code for ex/err management ...
END CATCH
```

This way, every `Tx` will lock a different row=`@Id` (`READPAST`) and if an error happen `XACT_ABORT`/`CATCH` will automatically rollback current `Tx` and `IsProcessed` will return to initial value `0`. `Work.Item` should have an index on `IsProcessed`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IUN_Work_Item_IsProcessed_Id
ON Work.Item (IsProcessed, Id)
```

Another option for indexing is to create a filtered index if number of IsProcessed = 0 will be [very] small compared with IsProcessed = 1:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IUN_Work_Item_Id_IsProcessed0
ON Work.Item (Id)
INCLUDE (IsProcessed)
WHERE IsProcessed = 0
```

Note: see ["Required SET Options for Filtered Indexes" section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql) for proper SETtings during filtered index creation and DML execution. From my point of view, processed rows should be deleted (see Remus's approach), this way Work.Item tables will remain small.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about SET LOCK_TIMEOUT, I'll check if it works for me! I didn't want to merge the select/update because of the "lock until it's released" problem, in my case I want to hold the lock until a specific operation is done (and it can take time).

Comment: @MicaëlFélix: What kind of lock (X, U, S ?), what statement and why ? Could you add more info regarding following requirement *" want to hold the lock until a specific operation is done"* ?

Comment: I have added information about my use case, it's for a queueing system, I want to use the transactionnal capability of SQL Server to prevent other "WorkerApp" (client C# app) to be able to handle a "WorkItem" more than once at a time. So the client apps will hold a transaction until their work has been completed, so if the client app fail for any reason (app crashing, pool recycling), it will simply rollback to IsRunning = 0

Comment: Then for `SELECT TOP(1) ...` I would use  `FROM Work.Item WITH(ROWLOCK, READPAST)` table hints. See also this article of Remus Rusanu about simulating queues using tables http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/.

Comment: @MicaëlFélix: Updated [ 5 ] to use CTE with TOP(1) and ORDER BY.

Comment: @MicaëlFélix: If current solution generates deadlocks then I would intercept deadlock graph events (with SQL Profiler or from default XE sessions: system_health) and I would publish deadlock graph in XML format here.

Comment: I'll go for solution #1 and solution #3 for the "WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)" so it doesn't get blocked trying to update a record in use by another transaction. In my case the "heavy work" is done in the C# "WorkerApp" so the solution 5 cannot apply because the whole transaction will be entirely driven by the C# client and not be closed until the work is done. At the end the resume of the work that has been completed will be put in an work history table (including result and timings for example), and the related workitem will be removed off the WorkItem table. Does it seem OK?

Comment: Seems ok with one note: I would use the solution 3.2 because it uses `ORDER BY workId` and thus the order of processing is guarantee. On a side note: I never used LOCK_TIMEOUT 0.

Comment: Yes, there will be an order by, I didn't write it for the sake of simplicity but I'll have a Prioritiy management so no specific client would be let down because its request arrived after one client that asked for thousand of works. Thank you for all your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how SQL Engine works, UPDATE statements will always ask for Exclusive Intent locks on the table.

The only way a query crashes from locks is if a deadlock happens or like Bogdan Sahlean stated with a `SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 0` but I greatly disrecommend this behaviour.

In your scenario, a deadlock will not happen since the UPDATE on the first query already happened when your 2nd query comes in. After first query finished, the 2nd query will execute normally (with "just" a long wait time before it).

If every process that encountered a wait-for-lock had to crash, your user experience would be VERY low, getting error messages instead of simple slowness.